# ng-newsletter - Immediately satisfying users with a splash page - errata corrige

Tags: angularjs

I was looking for a smart way to show a loader
before the page is loading and gooling I found
http://www.ng-newsletter.com/advent2013/#!/day/21

but imo there is an error in the tutorial
so I post the errata corrige (put me right if I'm wrong)

### CSS

```
[ng-cloak].splash {
    display: block !important;
}
/* some naive styles for a splash page */
[ng-cloak].splash {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
}
[ng-cloak].splash h2 {
    font-size: 2.1em;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.splash {display: none;}
```

### HTML

```
<div class="splash" ng-cloak>
    <h2>Loading</h2>
</div>
```

also you need to add a container with the ngCloak directive
to the rest of the app.

Comment: this isn't a question, why are you posting this here?

Comment: Yes, you're right and I apologize but in the ng-newsletter there is no comment section so to warn the error to the folks I didn't find a better place ^^